# Broadcomm 4356 WIFI chipset not claimed in Bionic Beaver

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have been using Ubuntu on a Thinkpad for a while, and while upgrading kernels in Bionic Beaver, the drivers seems not to be working anymore: 
I have tried every drivers available (br-4, brcm-brfmac, linux-headers etc...) and I can't find the problem. I'm not a tech genius but I have followed every detail (except for the card, which is unregistered) to solve this issue detailed here...
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

```
$ uname -a
Linux tachikoma 4.15.0-51-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 15 14:27:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -c network
/proc/cpuinfo
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e1400000-e1407fff memory:e1000000-e13fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: fc:45:96:20:cc:7d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:122 memory:e2a00000-e2a1ffff

$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43ec] (rev 02)

$ dmesg | grep wl ##(no response)

$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

~$ sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl
    [sudo] password for tachikoma: 
    [    3.507892] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
    [    3.507895] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
    [    3.509474] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
    [    3.511283] wl 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    3.519271] wl driver 6.30.223.271 (r587334) failed with code 12
    [    3.519272] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_detach : 
    [    3.519272] NULL ndev->ieee80211ptr, unable to deref wl 



        # wl module from Broadcom conflicts with the following modules:
    blacklist b43
    blacklist b43legacy
    blacklist b44
    blacklist bcma
    blacklist brcm80211
    blacklist brcmsmac
    blacklist ssb
tachikoma@tachikoma:~$ sudo modprobe -r wl
tachikoma@tachikoma:~$ sudo modprobe brcmfmac
tachikoma@tachikoma:~$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    3.617284] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4354A2-0a5c-640e.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.617287] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4354A2-0a5c-640e.hcd not found
[26492.789782] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[26492.897283] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin for chip 0x004356(17238) rev 0x000002
[26492.903037] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[26493.342395] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[26493.342409] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available(err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[26493.343549] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:41 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-1a5c4016
[26493.433356] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

So far I have tried the following kernels: b43, brcmfac, bcmwl-kernel-source.

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to diagnose the problem or repair it?

Comment: Your specific device is not listed in the usual Broadcom answer. I suggest that you try: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot.

Comment: @chili555 I've already tried that option, it didn't worked. when I try to reinstall it I get 'bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4).' I have also tried to purge and reinstall it without success...

Comment: Let;s check some diagnostics from the terminal: `dmesg | grep wl` and also:`rfkill list all`

Comment: There is no blacklisting of the wifi card (the bluetooth is soft blocked if I understand the command right)

Comment: It would be mush better if we could examine the actual messages. Please paste them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I have edited the message so everything is summed up in my question:dmesg | grep wl ##(no response)

$ rfkill list all 0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no 1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

Comment: Is there any error or warning if you do: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: yes there is! :)  printf("%d\n", 42);  /* :~$ sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl
[sudo] password for tachikoma: 
[    3.507892] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.507895] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    3.509474] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.511283] wl 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.519271] wl driver 6.30.223.271 (r587334) failed with code 12
[    3.519272] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_detach : 
[    3.519272] NULL ndev->ieee80211ptr, unable to deref wl */

Comment: Wow! brcmwl-kernel-source doesn't like your device *at all!* This usually reliable suggests that the correct driver is brcmfmac: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM94356Z Please unload wl: `sudo modprobe -r wl` and load brcmfmac: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` Then check the message log; it probably wants missing firmware: `dmesg | grep brcm` I suggest that you post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: It worked!! partially but it did! 'https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kQNkk8TsBV/plain/'

Comment: Partially? Are you offered networks to connect to? Does it try to connect? Does it drop or what? You may as well: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you remove the incorrect driver *wl*:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Next, blacklist the incorrect drivers b43 and ssb:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Now, let's install the correct firmware:

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
wget https://gist.github.com/autofyrsto/f02435e1fa0ecb7e7be23d54b2d54177/raw/abf184185e48c3df9e8d477d31f08e242fc13afc/brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt
exit
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.